# How to fix laminated wardrobe door?

Tags: repair, wood, laminate

Two chips have come off from the edge of our wardrobe door. I think it's some kind of laminated plywood, and was wondering if it would be possible to fix it in place, or at least without having to get another entire piece? I do have the chips stored, I'm not sure if just gluing them back would do the trick or if I'd need some kind of wood filler and forget the chips?

Comment: Does your door have any texture? If so I'd suggest to glue them back. Its nearly impossible to match the texture with wood filler. If the fallen chip has cracked and became smaller than the "hole", you may try to fill the hole with (wood glue+sawdust) mixture and paste the fallen chip on top.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a picture of the chipped area of the door and the chips as well. This will provide a lot more information toward repair options. Some things that would be answered from well lighted and focused pictures would be if the door is made of solid wood, plywood or particle board. Also answered would be if the door is finished with a sealer, veneer or plastic coating.